# Monitor Permission changes on Shared Folder using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, automation, acl, servicenow, fileserver

I am trying to write a script that would monitor changes on the shared folder's permission but not able to find anything. As per attached Image, if someone tries to add/remove any group or a user or change the permission here then I should be notified with user details and time.
Any of your suggestions or references are welcome.

[Shared folder which is used by others for accessing files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4BBT.png)

Comment: What aren't you able to find? How to write it, or a code that fits your description? Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I have used the same template "https://powershell.one/tricks/filesystem/filesystemwatcher"  provided by Rich Moss below for monitoring files and folders but not able to figure out how do I monitor the changes that would occur security permissions like group or user getting added there.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for a [FilesystemWatcher](https://powershell.one/tricks/filesystem/filesystemwatcher), but you'll need to make these code changes to monitor altered Security:

```
# specify the file or folder properties you want to monitor:
$AttributeFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::Security 

# specify the type of changes you want to monitor:
$ChangeTypes = [System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes]::Changed
```

Note that this script must always be running to monitor for changes. It may not be possible to monitor remote shares.

EDIT: Here's a minimal example distilled from the link above that watches for changes to security or file content. As recommended, I started with the asynch version to capture all events, not just the first one:

```
try {
  $watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher -Property @{
    Path = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
    Filter = '*'
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    NotifyFilter = @([IO.NotifyFilters]::Security, [IO.NotifyFilters]::LastWrite) #add any other notify filters to this array
    EnableRaisingEvents = $true
  }
  $handlers = .{#add any other events to listen for
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName 'Changed' -Action {Write-Host "`nChanged: $($event | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5)"}
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName 'Deleted' -Action {Write-Host "`nDeleted: $($event | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5)"}
  }
  Write-Warning "FileSystemWatcher is monitoring $($watcher.NotifyFilter) events for $($watcher.Path)"
  do{
    Wait-Event -Timeout 1
    Write-Host "." -NoNewline     # write a dot to indicate we are still monitoring:
  } while ($true)# the loop runs forever until you hit CTRL+C    
}finally{#release the watcher and free its memory
  $handlers | %{Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $_.Name }
  $handlers | Remove-Job
  $watcher.Dispose() 
  Write-Warning 'FileSystemWatcher removed.'
}
```

Comment: I have used the same template for monitoring purpose but was not able to figure out how do I monitor changes that would ocuur on security permissions (like a group or user getiing added or removed there). I will try to apply $AttributeFiIlter And $ChangeTypes and check if I can successfully use it. Will get back to you soon.

Comment: you can compare them to whats supposed to be there. Please provde a code

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I'm not good at PowerShell so I have just used the template that Rich has highlighted to use and tired.. not much changes made at it works perfectly but I want to get User details that would make any changes to shared path's security permission. Rich Moss script is also same. You can refer that. I have just added filename and directory name to be monitored.

Comment: @RichMoss Thanks you. I have tried your suggestion and the script provided but it doesn't help with user details. Eg: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7HoJ.png  - Refer the image... Here on shared path I'm trying to add a user "Demo.user" and grant him with Write access. So I want the script to provide detail of mine that I added Demo.user on path with Write access today. This is where I'm lagging to capture the details. Hope I was able to explain.

Comment: The script I provided reports all of the `$event` properties when a permission changes on the current user's desktop and subfolders.  You can change the `-Action` parameter to write today's date/time along with the path, but the event doesn't contain all the details about the change to permission. You can change the code to write the current permissions before starting the watcher, then change the `-Action` parameter to write out the changed permissions.

Comment: You can also look into [auditing ACLs](https://www.netwrix.com/how_to_audit_file_permission_changes.html).

Comment: Thanks Ross for the suggestion. But is there any way to get user details?

Comment: If you've executed the script above, you may have noticed that there isn't any property of the `$event` object that indicates what permissions were added or removed.  The FullPath of the changed file or folder, and the ChangeType are the only details. If you want to get the full detail of the change including the user you can either dump the permissions prior to the change and compare afterwards, or enable auditing the ACL changes.

Comment: Okay got it. I too think its the only option for now.